# Cant get server control's id using document.getElementById()

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am trying to pass asp panel id from button onclientclick method and    intend to show the panel but document.getElementById is fetching null value.
 why its not able to fetch the control's id.

here's the mark up:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnl1stDurationWaiverForm" Style="display: none" runat="server"></asp:panel>
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnYes" runat="server" OnClientClick="showDurationWaiver(document.getElementById('<%= pnl1stDurationWaiverForm.ClientID %>'))" Text="Yes"></asp:LinkButton>
```

here's the javascript method:

```
function showDurationWaiver(pnlCtrl) {
 debugger;
 if (pnlCtrl != null) {
    pnlCtrl.style.display = 'block';
 }
 return false;
}
```

Comment: How does the html code generated look like? On your browser check the code with the "view source" option to see the ids in there. Hint: make sure the id generated has not been duplicated somewhere in the html.

Comment: What is the output of _<%= pnl1stDurationWaiverForm.ClientID %>_?

Comment: this is the panel's id that generated at runtime 'repStartStopTimeCards_ctl00_uclStartStopTime_pnl1stDurationWaiverForm'

Comment: moreover the document.getElementById('<%= pnl1stDurationWaiverForm.ClientID %>') passed null value to the javascript method

Comment: What is the output of OnClientClick="showDurationWaiver(document.getElementById('<%= pnl1stDurationWaiverForm.ClientID %>'))" ?

Comment: i got the solution i put ClientIdMode="static" and passed the panel's id and it worked